# AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Set'

Tags: python, macos, collections, attributes, odoo

I'm facing a problem while trying to install odoo on mac m1 by typing python3 odoo-bin odoo15

```
odoo % python3 odoo-bin odoo15
```

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/odoo/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/Users/mac/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from . import osv
  File "/Users/mac/odoo/odoo/osv/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import osv
  File "/Users/mac/odoo/odoo/osv/osv.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..models import Model, TransientModel, AbstractModel
  File "/Users/mac/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 6598, in <module>
    collections.Set.register(BaseModel)
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Set'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see in the Python3.10 whatsnew, under the [Removed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed) section, the following:

> Remove deprecated aliases to [Collections Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) from the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#module-collections) module. (Contributed by Victor Stinner in [bpo-37324](https://bugs.python.org/issue37324).)

Unfortunatly , Odoo still use the deprecated alias [collections.Set](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/models.py#L6598) and to fix that error, you can downgrade your python version

Odoo 15.0 works fine in a virtual environment with Python 3.9.6 on a Linux machine