# how to solve odoo subprocess-exited-with-error?

Tags: python, odoo, requirements, cmder

i'm using odoo 14.0 version and python 3.10
pip install -r requirements.txt
whenever I write this it gives me the same error over and over
I tried almost all the solutions
it gives me this:

error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Comment: Ignoring gevent: markers 'python_version == "3.7"' don't match your environment
Ignoring gevent: markers 'sys_platform == "win32" and python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
Ignoring greenlet: markers 'python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
Ignoring greenlet: markers 'python_version == "3.7"' don't match your environment
Ignoring Jinja2: markers 'python_version < "3.8"' don't match your environment

Comment: Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [60 lines of output]
      warning: src\gevent\resolver\cares.pyx:38:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in-place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310

Comment: Compiling src/gevent/libev/corecext.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/gevent/libev/corecext.pyx
      Compiling src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py
      Compiling src/gevent/_hub_primitives.py because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing src/gevent/_hub_primitives.py
      Compiling src/gevent/_hub_local.py because it changed.

Comment: warning: src\gevent\_gevent_cgreenlet.pxd:112:33: Declarations should not be declared inline.

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      cdef load_traceback
      cdef Waiter
      cdef wait
      cdef iwait
      cdef reraise
      cpdef GEVENT_CONFIG

Comment: Odoo uses [deprecated collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71130842/attributeerror-module-collections-has-no-attribute-set) aliases which was removed in Python 3.10 so you can't use it

Comment: so i need to downgrade my python now?